# Can DynamoDB stream see an uncomitted transaction?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have a DynamoDB table where I am using transactional writes (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transactions.html). The transaction consists of 2 puts. Let's say the first put succeeds and the second fails. In this scenario, the first put will be rolled back by the transaction library.

I also have DynamoDB streams (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) enabled on the table and another application consumes from that stream.

Question: In the rollback scenario, will the first successful put result in a DynamoDB stream event and the rollback will result in another? If yes, is there is a way to prevent this, that is, to ensure that a stream event is triggered only for a fully completed transaction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transaction-apis.html

> Changes made with transactions are propagated to global secondary
>   indexes (GSIs), DynamoDB streams, and backups **eventually, after the**
>   **transaction completes successfully**. Because of eventual consistency,
>   tables restored from an on-demand or point-in-time-recovery (PITR)
>   backup might contain some but not all of the changes made by a recent
>   transaction.

So As I read it, you won't see anything in the stream till after the transaction completes successfully.